# generate "create tablespace" script without dbms_metadata.get_ddl

Tags: oracle, ddl

i want to create a "create tablespace"-script for from our production database. i already tried the following which leads to a ORA-31603:

`select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLESPACE',tablespace_name)  from dba_tablespaces where tablespace_name != 'SYSTEM'`

After googling i found that i need the `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` to use `dbms_metadata.get_ddl`. What i have is access to `DBA_TABLESPACES`.

Question: Is there a way to generate a "create tablespace"-script without the `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` using only `DBA_TABLESPACES`?

I would write the script on my own but i dont really know how to interpret the information given by `select * from DBA_TABLESPACES` (is AUOTEXTEND ON or OFF, how much is the initial SIZE and so on...).

Answer (score 1):

This is helpful if you know your data files path and give them the same names of as their tablespaces.
Also it generate some of you tablespaces if needed.

```
SELECT    'CREATE '
         || DECODE (ts.bigfile, 'YES', 'BIGFILE ') --assuming smallfile is the default table space
         || 'TABLESPACE "'
         || ts.tablespace_name
         || '" DATAFILE ''C:\Oracle\oradata\yourDATABASEname\'|| ts.tablespace_name || '.DBF'''
         || CHR (13)
         || CHR (10)
         || LISTAGG (
                   '  SIZE '
                || df.bytes
                || DECODE (
                       df.autoextensible,
                       'YES',    CHR (13)
                              || CHR (10)
                              || '  AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT '
                              || df.increment_by * ts.block_size
                              || ' MAXSIZE '
                              || CASE
                                     WHEN maxbytes < POWER (1024, 3) * 2
                                     THEN
                                         TO_CHAR (maxbytes)
                                     ELSE
                                            TO_CHAR (
                                                FLOOR (
                                                    maxbytes / POWER (1024, 2)))
                                         || 'M'
                                 END),
                ',' || CHR (13) || CHR (10))
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY df.file_id)
         || CHR (13)
         || CHR (10)
         || '  '
         || ts.logging
         || ' '
         || ts.status
         || ' BLOCKSIZE '
         || ts.block_size
             ddl
    FROM dba_tablespaces ts
         INNER JOIN dba_data_files df
             ON ts.tablespace_name = df.tablespace_name
   WHERE     ts.contents = 'PERMANENT'                --excludes UNDO and TEMP
         AND ts.tablespace_name IN ('YOUR_TABLESPACE LIST')
GROUP BY ts.tablespace_name,
         ts.bigfile,
         ts.logging,
         ts.status,
         ts.block_size
ORDER BY ts.tablespace_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Autoextend and size details can be found in the `DBA_DATA_FILES` table. A tablespace can have multiple files with different sizes and attributes if its not a `BIGFILE` tablespace.

An example of a simple create script (in 11g) without taking most special features into account (so please check your tablespaces for details such as compression and cryptography and add them to the script accordingly. See the full `CREATE TABLESPACE` reference [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7003.htm#SQLRF01403)) - and, as always, test thoroughly. Excludes `UNDO` and `TEMP` tablespaces:

```
  SELECT    'CREATE '
         || DECODE (ts.bigfile, 'YES', 'BIGFILE ') --assuming smallfile is the default table space
         || 'TABLESPACE "'
         || ts.tablespace_name
         || '" DATAFILE' --assuming OMF (Oracle-Managed File names) is used
         || CHR (13)
         || CHR (10)
         || LISTAGG (
                  '  SIZE '
               || df.bytes
               || DECODE (
                     df.autoextensible,
                     'YES',    CHR (13)
                            || CHR (10)
                            || '  AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT '
                            || df.increment_by * ts.block_size
                            || ' MAXSIZE '
                            || CASE
                                  WHEN maxbytes < POWER (1024, 3) * 2
                                  THEN
                                     TO_CHAR (maxbytes)
                                  ELSE
                                        TO_CHAR (
                                           FLOOR (maxbytes / POWER (1024, 2)))
                                     || 'M'
                               END),
               ',' || CHR (13) || CHR (10))
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY df.file_id)
         || CHR (13)
         || CHR (10)
         || '  '
         || ts.logging
         || ' '
         || ts.status
         || ' BLOCKSIZE '
         || ts.block_size
            ddl
    FROM    dba_tablespaces ts
         INNER JOIN
            dba_data_files df
         ON ts.tablespace_name = df.tablespace_name
   WHERE ts.contents = 'PERMANENT' --excludes UNDO and TEMP
GROUP BY ts.tablespace_name,
         ts.bigfile,
         ts.logging,
         ts.status,
         ts.block_size
ORDER BY ts.tablespace_name;
```

If you have multiple datafiles in a tablespace consider changing it to a `BIGFILE` tablespace.